# Characterization of a subset of the Sobolev space $H^k(0,2\pi)$ in terms of Fourier series

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, sobolev-spaces

Let $A:=\{ u \in H^k(0,2\pi): u^{(j)}(0)=u^{(j)}(2\pi) \mbox{ for } j=0,1,\ldots, k-1\}$, where $H^{k}(0,2\pi)\subseteq L^2(0, 2 \pi)$ is the Sobolev space of order $k$ on $(0, 2 \pi)$. Can we say that $u \in A$ iff 
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (1+n^2)^k |\hat{u}(n)|^2<\infty?$$
In the above series $\hat{u}(n)$ are the Fourier coefficients of $u$. We think that the answer to this question is affirmative because maybe we can identify $A$ with the Sobolev space of the torus $H^k(\mathbb{T})$, and use [this result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#The_case_p_=_2).

Do you know any reference for a characterization of $A$ with Fourier series?

Thank you for any help you can provide us.

Comment: Sure what are you not sure about ? In general $f \in H^k(0,1)$ iff there is a polynomial such that $\sum_n f(x+n) - p(x-\lfloor x \rfloor) \in H^k( \Bbb{R/Z})$, writing the Fourier series of $(\sum_n f(x+n) - p(x-\lfloor x \rfloor))^{(k)} \in L^2(\Bbb{R/Z})$ gives your expression

Comment: @reuns I don't know why we have that $f \in H^k(0,1)$ iff there is a polynomial such that $\sum_nf(x+n)-p(x- \lfloor x \rfloor) \in H^k(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$. I'm not sure if I can say the conditions about the derivatives on $0$ and $2 \pi$ says us that $f \in A$ iff $g(e^{i \theta}):=f(\theta) \in H^k(\mathbb{T})$.

Comment: If $f \in H^k(0,1)$ then $f^{(k)} \in L^2(0,1)$ so $f^{(k)} = \sum_n c_n e^{2i \pi nx}$ then $\sum_{n \ne 0} \frac{c_n}{(2i\pi n)^k} e^{2i \pi nx} =f + p \in H^k(R/Z)$